# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext error, Spring framework

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I have encountered a problem when it comes to the Springs framework, which leads to that the communication between the server and the database does not work.

The project that I created is a Spring project, then refactored to Maven.

At this line in the code:
`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("projectName/spring.xml");`

I get this error:
`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [projectName/spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [projectName/spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

But it does exist. And I've tried solutions for this problem such as writing `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml")` instead. This doesn't help however, since then Spring automatically looks in the folder **src/main/resources**. This doesn't work for me since my project structure doesn't allow me to add this folder and put a XML-file in it. If I try to create this folder, then it is automatically put inside the Java-resources folder, and Eclipse won't allow me to put XML in there.

This is how my project looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Kjg.png)

**Is there a way for me to declare where Spring should look for this spring.xml-file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(this.getClass().getResource("/spring.xml").getPath())
```

try the code above

hope that helped

Comment: Thank you! Changed it to `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(ClassName.class.getResource("/spring.xml").getPath());` since it's in a static method.

Answer (score 1):

The ClassPathXmlApplicationContext assumes that the file is on your classpath (Javy describes how to do load a resource from your classpath).

If you want to load the configuration from your file system (as you're doing), you might want to consider using FileSystemXmlApplicationContext instead. Using this mechanism to load your context you can pass a file system location as you're currently doing.

Comment: Thank you, but I should maybe avoid pinpointing the filelocation since I want to be able to move the server later on.

Comment: Sure, it depends on your use case. But to just "get it to work" I figured this might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't look at the `src/main/resources`, it looks at the classpath.

If you write `projectName/spring.xml` you need to have this file in `bin/projectName/spring.xml` or `build/projectName/spring.xml`. Where `bin` or `build` your build folder.

If you build a jar, this file should be in the  `jar!projectName/spring.xml`.

For the web-application this file should be in the `WEB-INF/classes/projectName/spring.xml`.

If you add `src/main/resources` at the class path, then content of this folder will be in the build folder. Maven adds `src/main/resources` at the class path automatically.

Sometimes you should rebuild (clean) your project in the IDE to have such files in the build folder.

Comment: Ok, I may have misunderstood where Spring looks from answeres to similiar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use "FileSystemXmlApplicationContext" as

```
ApplicationContext  context =  new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```